single stub matching: single stub which has different characterstics impedance than the line?
how do we use smith chart to match a transmission line using a single stub which has different characterstics impedance than the line?
can we denormalize the load admitance seen a a distance d and normalize it with characterstics impedance of the stub, but I am not sure?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The stub presents a parallel impedance at the point of connection. You would calculate its impedance using its length and characteristic impedance. Just apply the equations.
